# How to compare dateformat rather than using of time

Tags: vb.net

How can I compare the last characters using of month, day, and year or the completedate rather than using datetime, Example case is Textbox3 is greater than textbox9 because Textbox3 day = 26 and textbox9 day = 25.

Mycode:

```
'in my case I have 2 Textbox. 
'Date format:   hh.mm MM/DD/YYYY 

'Textbox3= 02.02 03/26/2014 
'TextBox9= 21.01 03/25/2014

If Val(Strings.Left(TextBox9.Text.Trim, 5)) < Val(Strings.Left(Textbox3 .Text.Trim, 5))Then
    TimeError.ShowDialog()
End If
```

Comment: Why not use [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx)? What is the problem with it?

Comment: do yourself a favor and dont use `Val`

Comment: Why would you do such a thing?  The only reason that I can think of is that this is homework and you are obliged to do it that way because they're trying to teach you string manipulation.  Is that the case?

Answer (score 1):

Really, the fastest, most reliable, and most effective way to do this is to parse the values into a DateTime. And taking a step back from there, the fastest, most effective way to get a date time from a textbox is to use a [DateTimePicker control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

But if that's not an option, we can build on the code I gave you last time:

```
Dim temp1() As String = Textbox3.Text.Trim().Split(" .".ToCharArray())
Dim temp2() As String = Textbox9.Text.Trim().Split(" .".ToCharArray())

If DateTime.Parse(temp2(2)) < DateTime.Parse(temp1(2)) Then
    TimeError.ShowDialog()
End If
```

I'll add that you probably want to also have code to compare the time values in the case where the date portions are equal. Given this as a starting point, you should be able to write that code on your own.

Answer (score 0):

in vb.net you can comopare dates like this:

```
dim date1 as date = cdate(Textbox1.text)
dim date2 as date = Date.now()


    if date1.date=date2.date then ....
```

and months like this

```
if date1.month=date2.month then ...
```